# Re-open to correct closing reason

Tags: support

Question concerned: [Comparing the sizes of countable infinite sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125412/comparing-the-sizes-of-countable-infinite-sets#comment289896_125412)
This question could be helpful to others if closing reason is changed from 'Not a question' to 'duplicate'

Comment: The real question here is: what does it mean to **close** a question that has 2 answers, one of which is accepted!!! The fact that vote-close is an option **after an answer was accepted** does not make much sense to me. I can understand *protecting* the question, but closing?

Comment: @J.D.: a silly example would be a questing about say knitting on math.se; there may be several knitting enthusiasts who give answers, one of which is accepted ...

Answer (score 5):

Ah, it wasn't clear from your flag that you just wanted the closing reason changed. I thought you wanted the question re-opened as an open question, so I referred you to meta. Sorry about that. I'll go and change the closing reason now.

My apologies.